# jQuery draggable and droppable calculation based on an array with item ID's is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

I made a picture with some test cases just to show you when the calculation goes all wrong. In case 3, it would of worked if I moved out Item 1 instead of Item 2. After a few hours on trying to fix this I'm starting to feel a bit blind.

What is wrong with the calculation, could it be the events? Is there a better way of doing this?

[image]

Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ejasun/1/edit

Code:

```
var price = 0, math = '', items = [], state = 'outside';
$(function() {
  function calcPrice(math) {
    var value = null;
    if(items.length === 0) {
      price = 0;
    }
    console.log("Item array: " + items);
      $.each( items, function( key, value ) {
        if(math == 'add')
          price += $(".draggable[data-item='" + value + "']").data('price');
        console.log("Total price: " + price);
        if(math == 'remove'){
          console.log("Total price " + price + " -= " + $(".draggable[data-item='" + value + "']").data('price'));
          price -= $(".draggable[data-item='" + value + "']").data('price');
        }
      });
    $("#droppable").text(price);
  }
  $(".draggable").draggable({ containment: "#container", scroll: false });
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(e, u) {  items.push(u.draggable.data('item'));
      price = 0;
      calcPrice('add');
      u.draggable.data('state', 'inside');
    },
    out: function(e, u) {
      if(u.draggable.data('state') == 'inside') {
        u.draggable.data('state', 'outside');
        items.splice($.inArray(u.draggable.data('item'), items,1)); 
        calcPrice('remove');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="droppable"></div>
    <div class="draggable" data-item="2" data-price="542" data-state="outside">item: 2<br>price: 542</div>
    <div class="draggable" data-item="1" data-price="541" data-state="outside">item: 1<br>price: 541</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function is wrong and [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) as well. You could just do this:

```
var price = 0, math = '', items = [], state = 'outside';
 $(function() {
  function calcPrice(math) {
   var value = null;

   price = 0;

console.log("Item array: " + items);
  $.each( items, function( key, value ) {
    price+= $(".draggable[data-item='" + value + "']").data('price');

  });

$("#droppable").html(price);
}

 $(".draggable").draggable({ containment: "#container", scroll: false });
 $("#droppable").droppable({
   drop: function(e, u) {  
     items.push(u.draggable.data('item'));
     price = 0;
     calcPrice('add');
     u.draggable.data('state', 'inside');
  },
   out: function(e, u) {
     if(u.draggable.data('state') == 'inside') {
       u.draggable.data('state', 'outside');
       var myIndex = $.inArray(u.draggable.data('item'), items);
       items.splice(myIndex, 1);
       price = $("#droppable").text();
       calcPrice('remove');
     }
   }
 });
 });
```

if you want to just add and remove price when you drop something in or drag something out.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in your code:

**Issue1:**
On `drop:` you are not checking if the element already exists in the list. You need to set an Id for each element and on drop see if the `items[]` has an element with same Id. In your code if I drop the same element from in drop box multiple times it adds the price each time.

**Issue2:**
It is the issue that you describe. To clarify what is happening here. Your code does not remove the opposite value. It removes the price equal to what is left in the array (in drop box). So your logic in `out:` needs to be modified.

So you need to re-think your logic in both `drop:` and `out:`

Comment: Issue1: this one I'm aware of and I therefore didn't make a case for it. My solution is to use data-state. If data-state = "inside" it won't run the calc function. On the out: event it will set the data back to data-state = "outside". 

Would you mind telling me how you think the logic for issue2 should look like?